# Play 2.1 Scala - JSON - Symmetric Format object with nested data structure not serializing correctly

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I'm having some trouble writing a Format object for some JSON in Play 2.1 Scala. My (greatly simplified) JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "data": {
    "foo": "teststr1",
    "bar": "teststr2"
  }
}
```

I want to serialize/deserialize this to a slightly simpler, flattened format:

```
case class TestData(id: String, foo: String, bar: String)
```

My initial attempt at this looks like so:

```
implicit val testCaseFormat: Format[TestData] = (
  (__ \ "id").format[String] and
  (__ \ "data" \ "foo").format[String] and
  (__ \ "data" \ "bar").format[String]
)(TestData.apply, unlift(TestData.unapply))
```

That works fine when *reading* the data, but when writing only the last "data" value (`bar`) exists in the output JSON, presumably because the `data` object is being overwritten for each subsequent value:

```
{
   "id" : "id-1",
   "data":{
     "bar":"teststr2"
   }
 }
```

Is there a correct way to do this flattening and unflattening, without resorting to separate `Reads` and `Writes` objects? My actual data structures are quite large (although not too complex) so conciseness is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could/should create your format in a regular fashion:

```
(__ \ "id").format[String] and
(__ \ "data").format(
  (__ \ "foo").format[String] and
  (__ \ "bar").format[String]
  tupled
)
```

And then just supply different `apply` and `unapply` methods.

```
def specialApply(data:(String, (String, String))) = {
  val(id, (foo, bar)) = data
  TestData(id, foo, bar)
}

def specialUnapply(data:TestData):Option[(String, (String, String))] =
  Option(data) map { testData =>
    (testData.id, (testData.foo, testData.bar))
  }
```

### Edit

You can avoid adding the methods to the companion objects by composing the apply and unapply methods in place:

```
implicit val testCaseFormat: Format[TestData] = (
    // ...
)(TestData.tupled.compose { data:(String, (String, String)) => 
    val (id, (foo, bar)) = data
    (id, foo, bar)
  }), unlift(TestData.unapply))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it would certainly work, but I suspect the extra boilerplate I'd have to add for the specialApply and specialUnapply methods would outweigh that of just making a custom Writes to handle the "unflattening". As I said, my actual data structures are quite large with lots of nested case classes. I'll mark this as the answer if no-one has any other ideas in a few days.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show an option that minimizes boilerplate

Comment: Cool - I've marked this as the answer since it does seem to be the only way to do what I want. Meanwhile, I've filed a bug detailing how I think this the Play JSON way differs from expected behaviour.

Comment: For completeness, a link to the issue: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/1000-Serializing-selective-attributes-of-a-case-class-to-a-nested-JSON-object-discards-all-but-last-selected-attribute